# How to update a number of Rows in a Table using Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using the following code to update the UserSession column of the Activities. Following code return the records if the ExpiryTimeStamp is less then current date.
Then it Update the UserSession column to 0 for the returned recods in the table. 
 .Now I wants that if there are 100 records are returned then these should update at one time instead of using the FoREach. Is it posible in Linq

```
CacheDataDataContext db = new CacheDataDataContext();
                var data = (from p in db.Activities
                            where p.ExpiryTimeStamp < DateTime.Now
                            select p).ToList();
                data.ForEach(ta => ta.UserSession = "0");
                db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no: Linq-2-sql does not do batch updates out of the box.

(I am not sure your foreach will work like you wrote - i do not think so - but this is similar and will work)

```
foreach (var x in data)
{x.UserSession = "0";}
db.SubmitChanges()
```

BUT, even if you do it like this, Linq-2-sql will send an update statement for each record to the database. So with your example of 100 records returned you will get 100 individual updates send to the database.